# How to encrypt outgoing connections from a local device?

Tags: macos, mac, internet

ISPs' throttle internet traffic, so some provide fast lanes for popular websites while all other websites are available to the user at lower internet speeds or bandwith.

I am on an iMac so my question is that is there any way by which I can encrypt outgoing connections from my iMac in-order to escape internet capping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a VPN to automatically encrypt all your traffic, see [The best VPNs for Mac OS in 2017](http://www.techradar.com/news/best-vpn-for-mac-our-5-top-choices) or other recommendation lists for options. It depends on the VPN provider though whether they allow all kind of traffic though, some of them block/throttle torrents for instance. A VPN also doesn't protect you from ISPs throttling all VPN traffic by default.

Comment: Then is there anyway to completely encrypt outgoing connections using Terminal (pf or BSD pf)

Comment: Encryption requires two parties, one at each end of an connection. Just encrypting what you send won‘t do any good if there is nobody around to decrypt it